# Value won't increment inside while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

my problem is that the 'month' value increments once to month = 1, then stays there the whole time, causing an infinite loop. How do I get this to change every time through the loop? I know I'm probably missing something extremely simple.

```
def rem_bal(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyInterestRate):
    month = 0 
    while month <= 12:
        monthly_interest = (annualInterestRate) / 12.0
        minimum_monthly = (monthlyInterestRate) * balance
        monthly_unpaid= (balance) - (minimum_monthly)
        updated_balance = round(((monthly_unpaid) + (monthly_interest * monthly_unpaid)), 2)
        month =+ 1 
        print("Month " + str(month) + "Remaining balance: " + str(updated_balance) + " .")
        balance = updated_balance
    return balance
```

Answer (score 4):

```
month += 1
```

not

```
month = +1
```

which is just

```
month = 1
```

Comment: @RL13 happens to everyone

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be `month += 1` not `month =+ 1`; the latter is just plain assignment rather than incrementing  the value of `month` (i.e., assigning `month` to `+1`/`1`).

Answer (score 0):

BTW, this is not how you write a code in python.
Why parentheses around almost everything?
Why recalculate monthly_interest over and over, when it doesn't change?
Using a while loop for this isn't pythonic. You should rather use

```
for month in range(13):
```

Comment: Thank you- yeah I realize it's not ideal... I wrote out all the equations first just so I could look at them and ended up just copying them over which is why all the parenthesis are intact. And you're correct, I didn't have to recalculate the interest- I just forgot to remove it.

Comment: Also, why is it better to use for...range instead of a while loop?

Comment: @RL13 The short (and not so informative answer) is that because it is more "pythonic". The real advantage is that `for` is more explicit. You see immediately the looping condition, you don't need to check the code to see what is happening with the `month` variable inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

month = month+1  - tried this works